# How to add value in the last of the linkedlist

Tags: java, linked-list

How to add value in the last of the linked list. When I run the code, addAtLast() method does not return the updated list. The last value i.e. 50 is not added to the returned list.

```
public Node addAtLast(Node head, int data) {

    Node temp = head;
    Node newNode = new Node(data);
    while (null != temp)
        temp = temp.next;
    temp = newNode;
    System.out.println(temp);
    return head;

}
```

......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here :

```
temp = newNode;
```

you assign the new element to a `temp`  variable that is never associated to your linkedlist because assigning a reference to a variable makes it to point to a new thing.

Besides, what you need is to stop the iteration as the current element has no next element and not as the current element is `null`. Otherwise you don't keep a way to reference the last element but `null`.

You should write something like :

```
while (temp.next != null)
    temp = temp.next;
// here temp refers the last element of the chain as it doesn't have next element
temp.next = newNode;
```

Answer (score 1):

`temp = newNode;` has no effect on the original linked list.

In order to add a `Node` at the end of the list, you must find the last `Node`, which is the first `Node` for which `temp.next == null`. Then you modify `temp.next` of that `Node` to refer to the new `Node`.

```
public Node addAtLast(Node head, int data) {
    if (head == null) { // handle adding the first Node
        return new Node(data);
    }
    Node temp = head;
    Node newNode = new Node(data);
    while (temp.next != null) {
        temp = temp.next;
    }
    temp.next = newNode;
    System.out.println(temp);
    return head;
}
```